# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode' in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

while using  "GetPreLoginBanner" keyword  i am getting below error

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

Testcase
   ${RemoteServer}=    openconnection    127.0.0.1    port=2424    
    Login    ubuntu    ubuntu
    ${banner} =    GetPreLoginBanner    
    Log    ${banner}
```

Error:

```
FAIL : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\library.py", line 1005, in get_pre_login_banner
    return banner.decode(self.DEFAULT_ENCODING)
Ending test:   Hits.Builtkeys.SSHLibrary.LoginBanner
```

can someone help solving this error.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in SSHLibrary. It's assuming that `banner` is some sort of string, but in this specific case it's `None`.